# Best Configuration For Youtube HD 720p

Tags: video, youtube

I'm recording a screencast with **CamStudio** (http://camstudio.org/) . My computer's screen resolution is 1280*800 , so video's resolution is 1280*800, too. I'm using **Microsoft Video 1** codec when recording. I was record 9 minutes video and this video's size is **214 MB** .

I will upload this video to Youtube. I'm coding a web site at the video, because of this, video must be quality (720p) .

I want to reduce file's size, before upload . I'm using **Total Video Converter** (http://www.effectmatrix.com/total-video-converter/) . But when i convert to FLV , video's size increase to 250MB :)

I don't know, how can i configure this setting and which file type should i choose. (screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se0EP.jpg )